# Can't use timer(debounce purpose) with async validator - Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I am going to call API to validate an email address with debounceTime, there are solutions in the community.

```
new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl(cachedValue.firstName, [Validators.required]),
            lastName: new FormControl(cachedValue.lastName, [Validators.required]),
            email: new FormControl(cachedValue.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email],
                [this.validateUniqueValueEmail]),
            phone: new FormControl(+cachedValue.phone, [Validators.required],
                [])

        });

private validateUniqueValueEmail(control): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return timer(500).pipe(
            switchMap((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                return of({validationError: 'This email is already taken'});
            }),
        );
    }
```

This is supposed to be working, but I am getting following error.

core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on stackblitz

Comment: ensure that `of` is imported from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: this is import import {Observable, of, Subject, timer} from 'rxjs';

Comment: @blackiii you're right, my bad. I meant just `rxjs`

Comment: @SachinGupta, I tried on stackblitz , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8afddo it works without any error.... can't reproduce it. Maybe rxjs version?

Comment: `rxjs` may not be a problem. Though you may try it by changing the versions in stackblitz.